# Wait a new message to send while the current message is on process in smslib

Tags: java, smslib

my code is still working and I can send a message and wait until the message has been sent. The duration of sending a message is all about 10 seconds which is not good for me because my program needs 1 seconds interval before the next message to send. take a look to clarify the problem.

> msg4 -> msg3 -> msg2 -> msg1

msg4, msg3 and msg2 are still waiting until the msg1 has been sent/failed.

here is the code **sendMessage.java**

```
    public void doIt(String mobile_number, String message) throws Exception
    {
            OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
            System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
            System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
            System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
            SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com5", "COM5", 921600, "", "");
            gateway.setInbound(true);
            gateway.setOutbound(true);
            Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
            Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
            Service.getInstance().startService();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Modem Information:");
            System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
            System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
            System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
            System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
            System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
            System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
            System.out.println();



            OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage(mobile_number, message);
            Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);

            System.out.println(msg);
            System.out.println("Now Sleeping - Hit <enter> to terminate.");
          //  System.in.read();
            Service.getInstance().stopService();
    }
```

in my **main.java** class

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  new sendMessage().doIt("09483221***","This is the message");
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

The first message was successfully sent but the second one and so on was unsent.
How to make these to wait until the first message has been sent?

Answer (score 0):

once you send 1st message your port is unavailable to for the next sms thats why u cannot able to send second sms 
the solution once send your first sms terminate the port and send second sms